# Java Program Circumference and Area

Tags: java, variable-declaration

I got the assignment to write a Java program that gives the circumference and area of a circle of radius 1 through 50. This is what I've got:

```
public class Circles {

public static void main(String[] args) {


}   
{
    for (int i = 1; i <=50; i=i+1)
     area = PI * (radius * radius);
      System.out.println("The area is " + area);
      double circumference= PI * 2*radius;
      System.out.println( "The circumference "+circumference) ;
   }


}
```

It says that radius, pi, and area cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Where are you declaring those variables...?

Answer (score 0):

Because you never declared them as variables (nor, in the cases of `PI` and `radius`, even give them values).  Notice that it did *not* complain about `circumference`, which you *did* declare.

Comment: How would I write two methods one for calculating area and one for calculating circumference?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variables - at the moment you're only declaring two of them, namely `i` and `circumference`. Also, Java has a `PI` constant which is found in the `Math` class, so you'll need `Math.PI`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <=50; i=i+1) {
         double radius = i;
         double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
         System.out.println("The area is " + area);
         double circumference = Math.PI * 2*radius;
         System.out.println( "The circumference "+circumference) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Circles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double PI = Math.PI;

        for (int radius = 1; radius <=50; i=i+1) {
           double area = PI * (radius * radius);
           System.out.println("The area is " + area);
           double circumference= PI * 2*radius;
           System.out.println( "The circumference "+circumference) ;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Why od we put double and Math infront of PI?

Comment: double is the type of the variable, Math is the class containing the constant PI.